# How can I determine the amount of time a set of operations in C# require to execute?

Tags: c#, benchmarking

Is there a high precision timer that I can use to benchmark the amount of time a series of operations/statements take when executing ?  A timer that returns the number of seconds since epoch would be insufficient, as the resolution is in seconds.

I am thinking that the general implementation would be:

1. Get starting time in milliseconds.
2. Execute statements.
3. Get ending time in milliseconds.
4. Elapsed time = end - start.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Don't forget to take into account that the first time you call some code, the jitter has to jit it, but the second, third, ... millionth time you call it, the previously jitted code is used. Forgetting to account for the difference between the first call and the subsequent calls is an extremely common error when writing benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Is there some way to programmatically, interrogate the system to know if it JIT'ed and then leave that benchmark out ?

Comment: What I do (if I don't care about the jit time -- sometimes that is the thing that I am profiling since I often want to measure startup time), I simply run all my tests ten, a hundred, or whatever times and discard the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class works well for this.  Note that it measures wall clock time, not code execution time.

```
    Stopwatch sw= new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    DoTimeConsumingOperation();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed); // in milliseconds
```

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by
>   counting timer ticks in the underlying
>   timer mechanism. If the installed
>   hardware and operating system support
>   a high-resolution performance counter,
>   then the Stopwatch class uses that
>   counter to measure elapsed time.
>   Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses
>   the system timer to measure elapsed
>   time. **Use the Frequency and
>   IsHighResolution fields to determine
>   the precision and resolution of the
>   Stopwatch timing implementation**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I will implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a `Stopwatch` object for that, it has `Start` and `Stop` methods. However, note that it measure total time, not net time, which might be affected by the load on your system. To get net time you need to use some specialized profiling tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Can you elaborate on what you mean between total and net time ?  I am guessing that when you mention load as a factor that the time would vary depending on load, so a better benchmark would be running this at different loads and averaging it out ?  Or by using profiling tools ?

Comment: Only profiling tools would provide an accurate measurement, but if you don't need high accuracy, looping over the operation a few hundred times and dividing the time by the number of iterations (i.e. averaging) - would suffice.

Comment: Do profiling tools simulate varying workloads while the benchmarking is taking place ?

Comment: No they don't they measure the exact number of cpu cycles spent actually running your code, so they factor out everything else.